# Rails, Gmaps4rails, geocoder, google map marker clusters strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, markerclusterer, rails-geocoder

on my search page I have a google map with markers for each 'job'. I have made the map default to zoom level 2, where the markers cluster correctly, but as soon as I pass zoom level 5, clustering stops working. I have searched and haven't found any information on this.

Search page map javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var mapStyle = [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":33}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2e5d4"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5dac6"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5c6c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e4d7c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#fbfaf7"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#acbcc9"}]}];
  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({
      provider: {
        styles: mapStyle,
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.68177501, -103.3514794)
      },
      internal: {id: 'map'}},
      function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
  </script>
```

Jobs controller:

```
 def index
    if params[:search].present?
    @q = Gig.near(params[:search], 200, :order => 'distance' ).ransack(params[:q])
    @gigs = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@gigs) do |gig, marker|
      marker.lat gig.latitude
      marker.lng gig.longitude
      marker.title gig.title
    end
    else
@q = Gig.ransack(params[:q])
    @gigs = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@gigs) do |gig, marker|
      marker.lat gig.latitude
      marker.lng gig.longitude
      marker.title gig.title
    end
  end
end
```

Any insight into this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant code [lives here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee#L122-L124).

[Here is](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee#L3-L11) where you can customize the behavior.

So you can adpat the maxZoom level :

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { 
  markers: { 
    clusterer: { 
      maxZoom:  8, 
      gridSize: 50 
    }
  }
});
```